# Why is my page loading the php file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I need help with this, when I press the submit button I want my echo to show in the page where i have my span, not in a new page like (../addIPSE.php)...

my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jQueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/addIPSE.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header" position="fixed">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <form id="addIPSEform" action="addIPSE.php" method="post">
            <label for="addIPSE">IPSE:</label>
            <input type="text" name="addIPSE" id="addIPSE" placeholder="IPSE..." value="" data-clear-btn="true">
            <button id="submitButton" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all">Submit</button>          
        </form>
        <span name="result" id="result"></span>     
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" position="fixed">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

my addIPSE.php

```
<?php
include_once('DBconnection.php');
$IPSE = $_POST['addIPSE'];

$lookForIPSEinDB = mysql_query("SELECT IPSE FROM myDB WHERE IPSE='$IPSE'");

if (mysql_num_rows($lookForIPSEinDB) != 0) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE myDB SET antal_login = antal_login + 1 WHERE IPSE='".$IPSE."'");
    echo "Already in DB, adding +1 antal_login...";
}
else {
    mysql_query("INSERT into myDB(IPSE) VALUES('".$IPSE."')");
    mysql_query("UPDATE myDB SET antal_login = antal_login + 1 WHERE IPSE='".$IPSE."'");
    echo "New IPSE added in DB...";
}
?>
```

my addIPSE.js

```
$("#submitButton").click( function() {
    var inputIPSE = $("#addIPSE").val();
    $.post( $("#addIPSEform").attr("action"), inputIPSE, function(info){ $("#result").html(info); });
});

$("#addIPSEform").submit( function() {
    return false;
});
```

Also when I press the submit button I first get to an all white page, then I have to refresh the page to see my echo, but the only echo I get is the "Already in DB..:", and it does not show in the span on my index page...

Comment: I'm just gonna submit an IPSE: `' OR SLEEP(10000000) OR 1='1` - Oh dear, I've crashed your server.

Answer (score 3):

Your form is redirecting to your php file. You need to remove that action AND tell the submitButton click even to preventDefault():

```
$("#submitButton").click( function(e) {
e.preventDefault()
var inputIPSE = $("#addIPSE").val();
$.post( $("#addIPSEform").attr("action"), inputIPSE, function(info){ $("#result").html(info); });
});
```

Also, mysql is deprecated, you need to switch to PDO or MySQLi

Comment: What does "mysql is deprecated" mean? Cant I use it?

Comment: You can, but the functions have been removed from PHP 7, so you should look into rewriting any code that uses mysql: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php